# JavaScript algorithm to match text as closely as possible (but not identical)

Tags: search, text, parse-platform, fuzzy-search

Do you have any advice for a JavaScript algorithm, which searches through a database of strings of text to find multiple matches as closely related as possible to one particular string? I want to use it to search through a Parse database.

For example:
I ate a chicken

Database:

I think I ate bad chicken for my lunch

I had chicken salad for breakfast

Had I eaten breakfast, I would have felt better.

It would be a large database and the search will have to repeat hundreds of times for different searches.

Comment: client side? server side js?

Comment: Almost every database will have something like `%LIKE%` that does this for you

Comment: which of the three database examples are you expecting to match the example phrase?

Comment: I would like to match all three of them but in the order of the most relevant. It is a table in Parse which I have to search through.

Comment: That's a job for the database to do, not your db client (be it the server or even the browser).

Comment: Parse is not going to give you the tools you really need to do this easily. most real DBs have tools, and PHP has http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php, but you won't find those goodies in the Parse API.